# How to calculate the integral only in real domain?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

I have the following integral:

```
Integrate[1/(Sqrt[2] + Cos[4 X] + Sin[4 X]), X, 
          Assumptions -> Element[X, Reals]] // Simplify
```

> ```
>  (-((1 + 3 I) + Sqrt[2]) Cos[2 X] + ((1 + I) - I Sqrt[2]) Sin[2 X])/(
>    4 ((1 + I) + Sqrt[2]) Cos[2 X] + 4 I ((-1 - I) + Sqrt[2]) Sin[2 X])
> ```

The result appears to be very complex and it depends on `I`.

What I want is to integrate over real numbers and get a real solution. How can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica SE. To start: 1) take the [introductory tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), since the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) consider accepting the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 8):

At first sight it seems surprising that one gets a result involving `I`, but this not especially surprising for those with a substantial practice in *Mathematica*.
Our integrand can be recast in many ways and so can the result.
Quite a straightforward way yielding a result in our case manifestly real exploits `TrigFactor`.

```
intd = 1/(Sqrt[2] + Cos[4 x] + Sin[4 x]);
intdf = TrigFactor[intd]
```

> ```
> 1/(Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[2] Sin[Pi/4 + 4 x])
> ```

```
int = Integrate[ intdf, x]
```

> ```
> Sin[Pi/8 + 2 x]/(2 Sqrt[2] (Cos[Pi/8 + 2 x] + Sin[Pi/8 + 2 x]))
> ```

We need not playing with external packages to get a satisfactory result.

```
D[int, x] - intd // Simplify
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

Answer (score 6):

The result is correct, but may be not optimal. This might be a grade "B" in cas integration tests:

```
ClearAll[x]
integrand = 1/(Sqrt[2] + Cos[4 x] + Sin[4 x]);
anti = Integrate[integrand, x];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Simplify[D[anti, x] - integrand]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can try [Rubi](https://rulebasedintegration.org/downloadRubi.html). This gets "A" grade because it is missing `I` in the anti

```
<< Rubi`
anti = Int[integrand, x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Simplify[D[anti, x] - integrand]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 6):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

expr1 = 1/(Sqrt[2] + Cos[4 X] + Sin[4 X]);

sol1 = Assuming[Element[X, Reals],
  Integrate[expr1, X] // FullSimplify]

(* -(((1 + I) + (2 I + Sqrt[2]) E^(4 I X))/((4 + 4 I) + 
    4 Sqrt[2] E^(4 I X))) *)
```

Verifying that `sol1` is a valid anti-derivative

```
D[sol1, X] == expr1 // Simplify

(* True *)
```

The imaginary part of `sol1` is a complex constant

```
I*Im[sol1] // ComplexExpand // FullSimplify

(* -(I/(4 Sqrt[2])) *)
```

Consequently, the imaginary part can be discarded

```
sol2 = (sol1 - I*Im[sol1]) // ComplexExpand // FullSimplify

(* -((2 + (1 + Sqrt[2]) Cos[4 X] + (-1 + Sqrt[2]) Sin[4 X])/
    (4 (2 + Sqrt[2] Cos[4 X] + Sqrt[2] Sin[4 X]))) *)
```

Verifying that `sol2` is a valid anti-derivative

```
D[sol2, X] == expr1 // Simplify

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a nice example of a problem showing the interplay between mathematics and a CAS tool moderated by the user.

Appoach 1:

Simplify the integrand before integrating, and then integrate to find an obvious real result:

```
In[120]:= f[x_] := 1/(Sqrt[2] + Cos[4 x] + Sin[4 x])

In[123]:= g[x_] := 1/Sqrt[2] 1/(1 + Cos[4 x - \[Pi]/4]) 

In[124]:= f[x] == g[x] // Simplify

Out[124]= True

In[125]:= h[x_] = Integrate[g[x], x]

Out[125]= -(Tan[\[Pi]/8 - 2 x]/(4 Sqrt[2]))
```

Approach 2:

Find the antidrivative `a[x]` by integrating, as you have done. Then plot the real and imaginary part of that antiderivative, notice that the imaginary part seems to be constant, and finally find an equvalent antiderivative `a1[x]` by adding an appropriate constant as which we chose `-a[0]`.

```
In[126]:= a[x_] = Integrate[1/(Sqrt[2] + Cos[4 x] + Sin[4 x]), x]

Out[126]= (-((1 + 3 I) + Sqrt[2]) Cos[
   2 x] + ((1 + I) - I Sqrt[2]) Sin[2 x])/(
4 ((1 + I) + Sqrt[2]) Cos[2 x] + 4 I ((-1 - I) + Sqrt[2]) Sin[2 x])

In[128]:= a1[x_] = a[x] - a[0] // Simplify

Out[128]= Sin[2 x]/(2 ((1 + Sqrt[2]) Cos[2 x] + Sin[2 x]))
```

This quantity is a real antiderivative, and this also confirms that the imaginary part was really constant.

See that the results are equvalent

```
In[145]:= a1'[x] == h'[x] // FullSimplify

Out[145]= True
```